# Change URL Address with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url

Hi i would like to change the url from:

http://example.com/news.php?id_news=1
to
http://example.com/news/1

and

http://example.com/works.php?id_works=14
to
http://example.com/works/14

with .htaccess

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring it out. Did you have a question?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0):

My guess out of the blue is something like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCondition %{QUERY_STRING} ^id_([a-z]+)=([0-9]+)$ 
RewriteRule /^%1\.php$/ %1/%2?
```